# Separating CSS DIV code to sections for PCs and for cellphones

Tags: css

In my CSS file, many properties are common for both, but others vary between browsing the webpage with a PC and a cellphone. I use `@media screen and (max-width: X px)` for this - there's one behavior for narrow and another for wide screens. Various solutions occurred to me:

**Two separate files/ section**

I could separate the CSS into two files, or into one with following architecture:

```
@media screen and (max-width: X px) {
  *whole CSS code for cellphones*
}
@media screen and (min-width: X+1 px) {
  *whole CSS code for PCs*
}
```

This would mean duplication of a big part of the code.

**Common section + specific sections**

Similar to above, but the common part is outside:

```
body {
  *common code for body*
}
*common code for divs*
@media screen and (max-width: X px) {
  body {
    *cellphone-specific code for body*
  }
  *cellphone-specific code for divs*
}
@media screen and (min-width: X+1 px) {
  body {
    *PC-specific code for body*
  }
  *PC-specific code for divs*
}
```

This seems ideal: it is handy for changing the constants like specific widths and heights (I have everything together, no chasing the constants through whole file), and it would be even handier if I needed to change the X constant or even to create some third version (say, for tablets). It have just one small drawback: it doesn't seem to be possible, or at least it didn't work when I tried it.

**Everything in specific divs**

This is what I actually use:

```
body {
  *common code for body*
  @media screen and (max-width: X px) {
    *cellphone-specific code for body*
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: X+1 px) {
    *PC-specific code for body*
  }
}
```

**My question is: what is the "best use" solution? If there are some difficulties about it, how to solve them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want support for older browsers, that don't support @media, you should only place styling inside the @media for mobile(assuming you will only properly support mobile browsers that support @media).
Styling for PC should then just be overridden by styling for mobile.

So, option 4?